# Crash when trying JSONSerialization

Tags: get, crash, swift4

Im working on a small project that receives info from a GET request.
There is a json response that im trying to get information from. and I get a weird crash.
This is the code:

```
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

        do {
            let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let jsonString:String = json!
            print(jsonString)
            let jsonObjects = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
            // crash here 
            let revenue = jsonObjects["revenue"] as? Float ?? 404
            print("revenue: \(revenue)")

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error:\(error)")
        }
```

and the log is printing this error:

```
 Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x10e567528) to      'NSDictionary' (0x10e5681a8).
2018-08-24 15:02:42.750890+0300 creatingp[18743:1290643] Could not cast     value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x10e567528) to 'NSDictionary'     (0x10e5681a8).
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this one?

Comment: As mentioned in the error, request response is an array not dictionary. try `as! [Any]` or if response is array of dictionaries `try as! [[String:Any]]`

Comment: The response you getting is array , but you given [string:Any] . change to [Any]

Comment: Thanks! Changin to [Any] fixed the crash!